# MongoDB update multiple subdocuments with or query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I want to make an update query for multiple subdocuments at once. I will be setting all the subdocuments statuses to passive where they satisfy the condition I give on query.

```
db.deduplications.update(  
{ $and: [ 
    { "_id": "189546D623FC69E3B693FDB679DBC76C" }, 
    { "DeviceVersionPairs.DeviceId": ObjectId("5822d0606bfdcd6ec407d9b9") }, 
    { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFolderId": ObjectId("5823110e6bfdd46ec4357582") },
    { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFileId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942a") },
    { "DeviceVersionPairs.VersionId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942b") }
] },
{ $set: { "DeviceVersionPairs.$.Status": "passive" }});
```

Above query finds exactly one subdocument, then it makes the update as I want it. But;

```
db.deduplications.update(  
{ $or: [ { $and: [ 
        { "_id": "189546D623FC69E3B693FDB679DBC76C" }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.DeviceId": ObjectId("5822d0606bfdcd6ec407d9b9") }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFolderId": ObjectId("5823110e6bfdd46ec4357582") },
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFileId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942a") },
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.VersionId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942b") }
    ] } ,   
    { $and: [ 
        { "_id": "189546D623FC69E3B693FDB679DBC76C" }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.DeviceId": ObjectId("56dfe1356caaea14a819f1e4") }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFolderId": ObjectId("583fb4bc6e7f341874f13bfc") }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFileId": ObjectId("583fb539e015b8a53fb71872") }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.VersionId": ObjectId("583fb4ca6e7f331874213584") }
    ] } ] },
{ $set: { "DeviceVersionPairs.$.Status": "passive" }});
```

When I populate the query segment with an or, and add the other items it gives error:

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: DeviceVersionPairs.$.Status"
    }
})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you mean that you just wanna update the sub docs in _id = "189546D623FC69E3B693FDB679DBC76C", and the DeviceId is two of your query, but don't update other sub docs?

Comment: I guess yes. Other `_id` may present in the `or` level, and not all the subdocuments are needed to be updated of all given `_id`s.

Comment: What is the reason of the downvote? Actually one might come here and learn that `$` positional operator cannot match with multiple subdocuments. Isn't this beneficial for the community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this error

> The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

because of your second query matched with **multiple sub-document**. Currently it is not possible to use the **positional operator** to update all items in an array using positional operator.

so to solve your problem you can follow this process

1. Find document using _id and to find sub document using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)
   and then
2. update each sub document and save document again

can try like this:

```
db.deduplications.find(  
{ $or: [ {
         "_id": ObjectId("583fc558668bde730a460e11") , 
        "DeviceVersionPairs":{
            $elemMatch:{ "DeviceId": ObjectId("5822d0606bfdcd6ec407d9b9") , 
            "CloudFolderId": ObjectId("5823110e6bfdd46ec4357582") ,
            "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFileId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942a") ,
            "DeviceVersionPairs.VersionId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942b") }}
    } ,   
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("583fc558668bde730a460e11") , 
        "DeviceVersionPairs":{
            $elemMatch:{ "DeviceId": ObjectId("56dfe1356caaea14a819f1e4") , 
            "CloudFolderId": ObjectId("583fb4bc6e7f341874f13bfc") , 
            "CloudFileId": ObjectId("583fb539e015b8a53fb71872") , 
            "VersionId": ObjectId("583fb4ca6e7f331874213584") }}
    } ] 
}).forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.DeviceVersionPairs.forEach(function (device) {
      device.status = 'passive';
    });
    db.deduplications.save(doc);
 });
```

Comment: Actually this is what I was trying to avoid. My query is already in this shape, now I am trying to increase the performance by making all update at once. But I am feeling now that it is not possible. Right?

Comment: This is enough of an answer to me right now. Thank you.

Comment: There is now a feature to allow this sort of update.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about what do you want, but if I were right, what you want may be $elemMatch.

Refer to [MongoDB Update Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) , and [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch)

When you wanna query into embedded documents, you can't use $and and $or directly, this is some kind of 'bug' of mongodb.

Comment: Can you show me how I can form the query I provided with `$elemMatch`?

Answer (score 0):

Use method `UpdateMany()` to update documents. According to framework and langauage this method will be different like `Update({multi : true});` or UpdateAll({});`

For example :

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   <filter>,
   <update>
);
```

Use `$set` to write.

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

```
try {
   db.restaurant.updateMany(
      { $or: []
      },
      { $set: { "DeviceVersionPairs.$.Status": "passive" } }
   );
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

Comment: Might be the way you are trying to filter records is not correct. You can't update multiple records by finding records using `_id`.

Comment: actually not related to the `_id` in the query, but the `$` positional operator. It is not able to match with multiple subdocuments. That's what I learned today.

Answer (score 0):

I have run below query. And it is working fantastic.

```
db.mm.update( { $or: [ {$and: [{"_id": ObjectId("581d18d41b6c5c752f11c87a")}] }, 
                       {$and: [{"_id": ObjectId("581a1a671b6c5c752f11c87b")}] } 
               ] 
          }, {$set : {"name": "abc3"}});
```

If first document not found , second one is updated. And if 1st one is found it is updating only 1st one.

You can see that in your question -> Error message it is showing `"nMatched" : 0` . It is not finding any documents. Confirm all ID's and reference ID's.

Comment: I can confirm that Id are correct. I was, just like you, suspicious about that response, hence I made an `.find` query too with the same `{$or: []}` query, and it returns the documents no problem. The problem is as @shaishab roy remarks with the positional operator `$`. It is not able to match with multiple subdocuments.

Answer (score 0):

please see whether array filters will help

```
db.deduplications.updateMany(
{ $or: [ { $and: [ 
        { "_id": "189546D623FC69E3B693FDB679DBC76C" }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.DeviceId": ObjectId("5822d0606bfdcd6ec407d9b9") }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFolderId": ObjectId("5823110e6bfdd46ec4357582") },
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFileId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942a") },
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.VersionId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942b") }
    ] } ,   
    { $and: [ 
        { "_id": "189546D623FC69E3B693FDB679DBC76C" }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.DeviceId": ObjectId("56dfe1356caaea14a819f1e4") }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFolderId": ObjectId("583fb4bc6e7f341874f13bfc") }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.CloudFileId": ObjectId("583fb539e015b8a53fb71872") }, 
        { "DeviceVersionPairs.VersionId": ObjectId("583fb4ca6e7f331874213584") }
    ] } ] },


     { $set: {
         "DeviceVersionPairs.index.Status": "passive" ,
       }
     },
    { 
    arrayFilters: [ 
            { $or: [ { $and: [ 
        { "index.DeviceId": ObjectId("5822d0606bfdcd6ec407d9b9") }, 
        { "index.CloudFolderId": ObjectId("5823110e6bfdd46ec4357582") },
        { "index.CloudFileId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942a") },
        { "index.VersionId": ObjectId("582311168cd396223499942b") }
    ] } ,   
    { $and: [ 
        { "index.DeviceId": ObjectId("56dfe1356caaea14a819f1e4") }, 
        { "index.CloudFolderId": ObjectId("583fb4bc6e7f341874f13bfc") }, 
        { "index.CloudFileId": ObjectId("583fb539e015b8a53fb71872") }, 
        { "index.VersionId": ObjectId("583fb4ca6e7f331874213584") }
    ] } ] }
          ]
    ,"multi":true, new:true
    },

    function (err, out) {
         //
    });
```