# Mongoose not updating multiple matches

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        id: 15,
        score: 10
      },
      {
        id: 14,
        score: 100
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        score: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "items": []
  }
]
```

Now, I try to update `items` whose id is `14,15` & used the following query.

```
db.collection.update({
  "items.id": {
    $in: [
      14,
      15
    ]
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "items.$.score": 444
  }
},
{
  multi: true
}
)
```

but it updated only the first match in `items` that is that is id with 15, what can be wrong?

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 15,
        "score": 444
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "score": 100
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "score": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "id": 2,
    "items": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB update multiple subdocuments with or query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904007/mongodb-update-multiple-subdocuments-with-or-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **arrayFilter**s with targeted array elements:
here is the  [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.collection.update({
  "id": 1
},
{
  "$set": {
    "items.$[ele].score": 20
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "ele.id": {
        "$in": [
          15,
          14
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

see play ground code https://mongoplayground.net/p/cdgu1aqLwsI

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Positional identifiers $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.collection.update({
  "items.id": {
    $in: [
      14,
      15
    ]
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "items.$[element].score": 444
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element.id": {
        $in: [
          14,
          15
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OZHdVA_uu-v)