# How change array of objects of field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
Let data = {
              _id : "7302774",
              count : 25,
              Itmems : [{
                           image: "abc",
                           url: "28rudjj.com"
                        },
                        {
                           image: "abcd",
                           url: "aaa.com"
                        }
                       ]
            }
```

My mongodb data

I hope, change url
Example `const oldUrl = "aaa.com" const newUrl = "bbb.com"`

```
Let data = {
              _id : "7302774",
              count : 25,
              Itmems : [{
                           image: "abc",
                           url: "28rudjj.com"
                        },
                        {
                           image: "abcd",
                           url: "bbb.com"
                        }
                       ]
            }
```

hope result

```
await strapi.query('item').model.updateMany([
        { items: { $elemMatch: { url: oldUrl } } },
        {
            $project: {
                items: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: '$items',
                        as: 'item',
                        cond: {
                            $eq: ['$$item.url', oldUrl]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { $set: { items: { url: newUrl } } }
    ])
```

I try this code and updateMany => aggregate also error help me mongodb god user!!

If you have any information you want, I'll give you more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose not updating multiple matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66657369/mongoose-not-updating-multiple-matches)