# pymongo + update n arrays from a document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a document in mongoDB like this :

```json
{
  "_id" : 0,
  "name" : "Sponge Bob",
  "values" : [ [10000, 90], [10001, 92]  . . .],
  "storages" : [{ "number" : 123, "timestamp": "2022-09-08"}, . . .],
  "timestamp" : "2022-09-08"
}
```

I want to delete a filtered `"storages"` objects filtered with a range date, the same thing to `"values"`, but with the number on the first element of the array.

I've trying to do something like :

```py
objects.update({"_id":1}, {"$pull" : {"timestamp" :{"$gt": date}}})
```

But I do realize that the `"$pull"` method in this case will not catch all the array of an object, but indeed all the document that will be filtered in that range filter.

So the question is : how do I do this kind of filter to this kind of elements inside the documents with pymongo ?

Comment: Are your dates really stored as strings, or are they hopefully stored as BSON dates?

Comment: They're stored as BSON dates, actually I just find out how to use update method to do a pull on storages values array, the issue is in how to do with the "values" super array

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to edit your question to show actual date format, your solution for `"storages"` and the issue you have with `"values"`.  It will help future readers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose not updating multiple matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66657369/mongoose-not-updating-multiple-matches)